# Break SQL Create Table Script into Blocks?

Tags: c#, regex

Is there a way to break up the CREATE TABLE blocks of a MS SQL database script into an array or collection using RegEx?

I know how to use the RegEx, but I can't seem to find the right pattern that matches it.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE [Company](
    [CompanyName] [varchar](255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [Address1] [varchar](255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [Address2] [varchar](255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [City] [varchar](255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [State] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [Zip] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Company] ON [Company]
(
    [CompanyName] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

GO
ALTER TABLE [Company] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Company_CompanyName]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [CompanyName]
GO
ALTER TABLE [Company] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Company_Address1]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [Address1]
GO
ALTER TABLE [Company] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Company_Address2]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [Address2]
GO
ALTER TABLE [Company] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Company_City]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [City]
GO
ALTER TABLE [Company] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Company_State]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [State]
GO
ALTER TABLE [Company] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Company_Zip]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Zip]
GO

GO

-- =============================================
-- Counties TABLE
-- =============================================
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [Counties](
    [UID] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [CountyName] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [StateUID] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [SurTax] [money] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I would just like to get all of the CREATE TABLE blocks into an array (between CREATE TABLE and GO) so I would have an array that only contained:

```
CREATE TABLE [Company](
    [CompanyName] [varchar](255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [Address1] [varchar](255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [Address2] [varchar](255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [City] [varchar](255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [State] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [Zip] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE [Counties](
    [UID] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [CountyName] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [StateUID] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [SurTax] [money] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like an XY problem. I'll just throw this out here: creating a database project with [SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt) allows you to import any script, and any objects created in that script become part of the database project. Not only is it much better at parsing scripts than any regex, but it's also better at representing databases in general. Even if it doesn't solve your problem, it's good to know it's out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the idea might be kind of brittle.
Anyway I would try something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE \[.*?\) ON \[PRIMARY\]
```

Check the [online demo](https://regex101.com/r/m940yn/2), where you can also find your example.
From that link, let me copy-paste the explanation:

- CREATE TABLE  matches the characters CREATE TABLE  literally (case
  sensitive)
- \[ matches the character [ literally (case sensitive)
- .*?    matches    any character
- *? Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
- \) matches the    character ) literally (case sensitive)
- ON  matches the characters ON  literally (case sensitive)
- \[ matches the character [ literally    (case sensitive)
- PRIMARY matches the characters PRIMARY literally    (case sensitive)
- \] matches the character ] literally (case    sensitive)

To make it work you will have to use the following option in your code:

```
var RegexOptions = RegexOptions.Singleline;
```

Which is the single line option for Regex, so that a Dot matches
   newline characters (otherwise you would stop at newline characters).

Comment: Awesome! That worked great. Thanks for taking the time to explain each symbol as well as that helped greatly for me to refine it. I ended up modifying the end a bit because it turns out that PRIMARY isn't always there and it doesn't even always end with that. Since (in my script) the last line of the CREATE statement always ended with a new line, followed by a GO, I modified it slightly like this: `CREATE TABLE \[.*?\) ON .*?\]\n`.     Thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad it worked, thank you for the good question; I didn't get why somebody downvoted it since it was perfectly reasonable

Answer (score 1):

Ummm

```
String.Split("go", StringSplitOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

and take .... Or something like that (where) is all u need here

Take it a step further and inline the altera...

Don't forget to upvoted my dude.